# weird problem with imagecreatefromjpeg()

Tags: php, csv, jpeg

I have a very weird problem, i am importing a product list into a new website from csv.
One part is to copy the image and resize it, but i am having a very weird problem with it.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/production/public/storage/Productimages/".$product['largepic'];
echo $path;
imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
```

If i execute this part I am getting this error:

```
/home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/public_html/production/public/storage/Productimages/1A(19).jpg
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/public_html/production/public/import.php on line 27
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: '/home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/public_html/production/public/storage/Productimages/' is not a valid JPEG file in /home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/public_html/production/public/import.php on line 27
```

But when i copy the full path that i am echoing:

```
/home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/public_html/production/public/storage/Productimages/1A(19).jpg
```

And use that like this:

```
imagecreatefromjpeg("/home/xxxx/domains/xxxx/public_html/production/public/storage/Productimages/1A(19).jpg");
```

Then it works!?

I hope someone can help :(

Comment: According to the error message, `$product['largepic']` doesn't make it into the path you pass to `imagecreatefromjpeg()`. Are you 10000% sure you have the correct code here?

Comment: Yes, thats the point, it has to be correct, because i echo the correct path. And if i copy that exact same path and use it again it works.

Comment: I just found the problem, the CSV had a weird Mac encoding which my server apparently didn't understand. But my browser did, so when i copied it back into my code it did understand. I recreate the csv on a windows pc and my problem is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet and see if it works.

```
$path = (string) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/production/public/storage/Productimages/".$product['largepic'];
echo $path;
imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
```

It could be problem with charset.

Comment: How is typcasting string to string going to help with charset problems?

Comment: I see a special characters "(" & ")" - so it leads me to there, so there could be a problem in reading these characters (?).